# Adding elevation data to a georeferenced image from TIN?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, 3d-analyst

I have a georeferenced image/tiff and a TIN layer (created from elevation line fc), and want to add the elevation data from the TIN to the image. How do I do this?

I know I can float the image over the TIN, but can I add the elevation values to it also?

I use ArcGIS 10.3

Comment: Why do you want to do that? At first sight it's not an efficient data structure.

Comment: I need to use the georeferenced photo (a recent ortphoto) to estimate the changes in elevation after this specific area recently was excavated.

Comment: You don't need to have both elevation values in the same raster to compare them. I would convert the TIN to a raster, then use Cut/Fill or Minus to detect the changes.

Comment: But the georeferenced image has no elevation values, only xy.

Comment: So how do you want to compare elevation? Visually?

Comment: I'd like to get the original terrain height on to the image and then add a layer with proposed increased elevation. So yes, it is for visualisation purposes.

Comment: Just a note that adding elevation values to the image won't change its visual appearance.  In my opinion, it would be better to clip your area of interest from your image, and use that as a mask to limit your analysis of the TIN and proposed increased elevation raster.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the added value to having both images in the same file for visual analysis purposes, but you can do this:

- convert the TIN to a raster with [TIN to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/tin-to-raster.htm),
- then create a multiband raster with [Composite Bands](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/composite-bands.htm).

([Combinatorial Or](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combinatorial-or.htm) is a useful tool to create unique combinations of values from 2 rasters (these have to be integer, so you might want to multiply elevation rasters by a constant to delete decimals while maintaining accuracy). But since your image doesn't have values, it isn't applicable here.)